# Ошибка при запуске VKBatchRequest

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, rxjava

При попытке выполнить и запустить следующий код:

```
VKBatchRequest vkBatchRequest = new VKBatchRequest(vkRequestsArray);
        vkBatchRequest.executeWithListener(new VKBatchRequest.VKBatchRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse[] responses) {
                super.onComplete(responses);
                ....
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                super.onError(error);
                ...
            }
        });
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxComputationScheduler-1


    Process: com.dugin_rostislav.vkmessagesforwarder_forwarder_service, PID: 21180
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.MessageQueue android.os.Looper.mQueue' on a null object reference
    at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:374)
    at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:371)
    at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onError(ActionSubscriber.java:44)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:157)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
    at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:204)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDelay$1$3.call(OperatorDelay.java:88)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$2.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:186)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.MessageQueue android.os.Looper.mQueue' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:238)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:146)
    at com.vk.sdk.api.VKBatchRequest.executeWithListener(VKBatchRequest.java:63)
    at com.dugin_rostislav.vkmessagesforwarder.VKBatchRequestsCreater.sendRequestInCycle(VKBatchRequestsCreater.java:75)
    at com.dugin_rostislav.vkmessagesforwarder.VKBatchRequestsCreater.access$100(VKBatchRequestsCreater.java:14)
    at com.dugin_rostislav.vkmessagesforwarder.VKBatchRequestsCreater$2.call(VKBatchRequestsCreater.java:109)
    at com.dugin_rostislav.vkmessagesforwarder.VKBatchRequestsCreater$2.call(VKBatchRequestsCreater.java:106)
    at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onNext(ActionSubscriber.java:39)
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:139)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDelay$1$3.call(OperatorDelay.java:88) 
    at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$2.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:186) 
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

В классе `VKBatchRequest`:

```
public class VKBatchRequest extends VKObject {
    private final VKRequest[] mRequests;
    private final VKResponse[] mResponses;
    private final VKRequest.VKRequestListener[] mOriginalListeners;
    private boolean mCanceled = false;

    /**
     * Specify listener for current request
     */
    public VKBatchRequestListener requestListener;

    public VKBatchRequest(VKRequest... requests) {
        mRequests = requests;
        mResponses = new VKResponse[mRequests.length];
        mOriginalListeners = new VKRequest.VKRequestListener[mRequests.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mRequests.length; i++) {
            mOriginalListeners[i] = mRequests[i].requestListener;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start new batch execution. At this moment a batch simply sends all requests with interval
     * @param listener {@link com.vk.sdk.api.VKBatchRequest.VKBatchRequestListener}
     */
    public void executeWithListener(VKBatchRequestListener listener) {
        if (mRequests == null) {
            provideError(new VKError(VKError.VK_REQUEST_NOT_PREPARED));
            return;
        }
        this.requestListener = listener;
/*ТУТ*/ Handler intervalHandler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());

        int nextInterval = 0;
        for (final VKRequest request : mRequests) {
            intervalHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final VKRequest.VKRequestListener originalListener = request.requestListener;
                    request.setRequestListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                            provideResponse(response);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(VKError error) {
                            provideError(error);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(VKRequest.VKProgressType progressType, long bytesLoaded, long bytesTotal) {
                            if (originalListener != null) {
                                originalListener.onProgress(progressType, bytesLoaded, bytesTotal);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    VKHttpClient.enqueueOperation(request.getOperation());
                }
            }, nextInterval);

            nextInterval += 1000 / 3;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cancel current batch request
     */
    public void cancel() {
        if (mCanceled) return;
        mCanceled = true;
        for (VKRequest request : mRequests)
            request.cancel();

    }

    protected void provideResponse(VKResponse response) {
        mResponses[indexOfRequest(response.request)] = response;
        for (VKResponse resp : mResponses) {
            if (resp == null) return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mRequests.length; i++) {
            VKRequest.VKRequestListener l = mOriginalListeners[i];
            if (l != null) {
                l.onComplete(mResponses[i]);
            }
        }

        if (requestListener != null) {
            requestListener.onComplete(mResponses);
        }
    }

    private int indexOfRequest(VKRequest request) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mRequests.length; i++)
            if (mRequests[i].equals(request)) return i;
        return -1;
    }

    protected void provideError(VKError error) {
        if (mCanceled)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i < mRequests.length; i++) {
            VKRequest.VKRequestListener l = mOriginalListeners[i];
            if (l != null) {
                l.onError(error);
            }
        }
        if (requestListener != null)
            requestListener.onError(error);
        cancel();
    }

    /**
     * Extend listeners for requests from that class
     */
    public static abstract class VKBatchRequestListener {
        /**
         * Called if there were no HTTP or API errors, returns execution result.
         *
         * @param responses responses from VKRequests in passing order of construction
         */
        public void onComplete(VKResponse[] responses) {
        }

        /**
         * Called immediately if there was API error, or after <b>attempts</b> tries if there was an HTTP error
         *
         * @param error error for VKRequest
         */
        public void onError(VKError error) {
        }
    }
}
```

На строке `Handler intervalHandler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());`, метода `executeWithListener()`, выскакивает ошибка.

---

Из-за чего эта ошибка и как ее исправить?

---

**UPD_0:** Два метода, в которых выполняется этот кода (второй метод перезапускает первый):

```
private static void sendRequestInCycle() {
        if (requests.size() == 0) {
            restartMethod();
            return;
        }

        final ArrayList<Request> requestsCopy = new ArrayList<>();
        requestsCopy.addAll(requests);

        ArrayList<VKRequest> vkRequests = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < requestsCopy.size(); i++) {
            vkRequests.add(requestsCopy.get(i).getRequest());
        }

        VKRequest[] vkRequestsArray = vkRequests.toArray(new VKRequest[vkRequests.size()]);

        VKBatchRequest vkBatchRequest = new VKBatchRequest(vkRequestsArray);
        vkBatchRequest.executeWithListener(new VKBatchRequest.VKBatchRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse[] responses) {
                super.onComplete(responses);
                for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
                    requestsCopy.get(i).getResponseListener().onComplete(responses[i]);
                }

                requests.removeAll(requestsCopy);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                super.onError(error);
                for (int i = 0; i < requestsCopy.size(); i++) {
                    requestsCopy.get(i).getResponseListener().onError(error);
                }

                requests.removeAll(requestsCopy);
            }
        });

        restartMethod();

    }

    private static void restartMethod() {
        Observable.just(true)
                .delay(REQUEST_PERIODICITY, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                        sendRequestInCycle();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: А если строчкой выше вызвать `Looper.prepare()`?..

Comment: покажите заодно и использование rxandroid для выполнения этого кода.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не помогло (хотя на что мы надеялись.. :)).

Comment: @zRrr, выложил.

Comment: @zRrr, как я понимаю, идей нет? :\

Comment: @zRrr, добавил полный код класса, может поможет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил полный код класса, может поможет.

Comment: ну попробуйте в `restartMethod` добавить перед `.subscribe` вызов `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`, тогда содержимое `call` будет вызвано в основном потоке, у которого `Looper` есть. Возможно, ошибка уйдет.

Comment: @zRrr, а разве оно не... :о Я же этот метод использовал только потому, что он продолжает выполнение в главном потоке.......

Comment: @zRrr, помогло, добавьте в ответ :).